# JS, setInterval для "светлофора"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Задание заключается вот в чём: есть три блока и надо правильно изменять их бєкграунд.

Вот то, что я пыталась сделать:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  red();
  setTimeout(yellow(), 2000);

});

function red() {
  var colors = [
    "red",
    "black"
  ];

  var el = $(".red");
  var i = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
    el.css("background-color", colors[i]);

    if ((++i) >= 2) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }, 2000);
}

function yellow() {
  var colors = [
    "yellow",
    "black"
  ];

  var el = $(".yellow");
  var i = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
    el.css("background-color", colors[i]);
    if ((++i) >= 2) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.main_block {
  height: 500px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.93);
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -120px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.red {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.green {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.red,
.yellow,
.green {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 50px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_block">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Алгоритм должен быть таким:

1. Красный светится 2 секунды
2. Желтый - 1 секунду
3. Зеленый - 3 секунды

Но я запуталась с setInterval-ами и setTimeout-ами.

Буду благодарна, если кто подскажет мне алгоритм выполнения всего этого. Т.е. все эти задержки должны быть правильно расписаны, но не пойму как

Спасибо за внимание

Comment: Я думаю, что setInterval  тут не нужен. Только setTimeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложу решение на css.

```css
.main_block {
  height: 500px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.93);
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -120px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.red {
  background-color: #000000;
  animation:red 6s steps(1) infinite;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: #000000;
  animation:yellow 6s steps(1) infinite;
}

.green {
  background-color: #000000;
  animation:green 6s steps(1) infinite;
}

.red,
.yellow,
.green {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 50px 0 0 -50px;
}
@keyframes red{
 0%{
  background-color: red;
 }
 33.33%,100%{
  background-color: black;
 }
}
@keyframes yellow{
 0%,50%,100%{
  background-color: black;
 }
 33.33%{
  background-color: yellow;
 }
}
@keyframes green{
 0%,100%{
  background-color: black;
 }
 50%{
  background-color: green;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="main_block">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как упомянуто в комментарии, интервалы тут вам и не нужны. Если следует переключать цвета в порядке `красный-желтый-зеленый-красный- ...` то можно поступить примерно следующим образом.

Если же цвета меняются по кругу, то есть, когда достигнут зеленый - то обратно желтый, то задача несколько сложнее, и нужно запоминать направление переключения.

```js
function change(){
  var duration = { red: 2, yellow: 1, green: 3 };  
  var $c = $(".main_block .active");
  
  //console.log($c.data('color'));
  
  setTimeout(function(){
       $c.removeClass('active');       
       
       var $next = $c.next();       
       if($next.length == 0) $next = $(".main_block .red");  
       $next.addClass('active');   
       
       change();
     }, duration[$c.data('color')] * 1000);  
}

change();
```

```css
.main_block {
  height: 500px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.93);
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -120px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.red {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.red.active { background-color: red; }

.yellow {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.yellow.active { background-color: yellow; }

.green {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.green.active { background-color: green; }

.red,
.yellow,
.green {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 50px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_block">
  <div class="red active" data-color="red"></div>
  <div class="yellow" data-color="yellow"></div>
  <div class="green" data-color="green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за вариант. Но "когда достигнут зеленый - то обратно желтый" - нет, не надо. Все намного проще, просто по кругу, то есть ничего запоминать не надо

Comment: @Біпач тогда приведенный код делает то, что вам нужно.

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, объяснить конструкцию "var $c"? Я ещё такого не видела о.о

Comment: @Біпач `var` объявление переменной, `$c` имя переменной, вас наличие `$` смущает?

Comment: Э, кто минусует там? :D

Comment: да, сначала знак $ засмущал, но потом вспомнила правила именований переменных в js)